# Entity Framework append where clause to SqlQuery call

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have the following raw query being executed through Entity Framework via a `SqlQuery` call on the `DbSet`:

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetComplicatedData<TEntity>()
{
    return database
        .Set<TEntity>()
        .SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM <Complicated Query Here>");
}

...

var count = GetComplicatedData<Item>()
    .Where(f => f.OwnerID == 5)
    .Count();
```

This works, but is very slow due to the fact that `SqlQuery` executes immediately without the `Where` getting applied.

Is there any way to call `SqlQuery` in such a way that the `Where` gets applied server-side?

Essentially, I want Entity Framework to generate a store query like:

```
SELECT 
    <Columns> 
FROM 
(
    SELECT * FROM <Complicated Query Here>
) a
WHERE a.OwnerID = 5
```

Or, is there a way to translate my where expression into a query that I can append manually (a.k.a, without manually writing a SQL query, the where clause is not always that simple)?

Comment: How does that work if `GetComplicatedData` is a `void` method?  What's stopping you from converting the complicated query into Linq?

Comment: @juharr Woops, sorry, I was writing pseudo-code for the question cause the actual code is too long.  I can't convert the code to LINQ, it's executing on a table that isn't part of the data model.

Comment: The next question: Why isn't that table part of the data model?

Comment: @juharr This is just what I have to work with.  The <Complicated Query Here> does a bunch of janky stuff in order to emulate the table at a point-in-time.

Comment: The closest thing I can think of that would support something similar in EF would be to implement `IDbCommandInterceptor` but it would be some work to do this properly especially if you want the query text you are using to be dynamic/configurable.

Comment: @Igor That's what I am currently experimenting with.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This cannot be done with LINQ methods, because "raw" queries are of type [`DbRawSqlQuery<TElement>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn159825(v=vs.113).aspx), which lacks support required for "composing" dynamic queries with `Where`.

If you are interested in counting items, you could work around the issue by taking a condition:

```
public int CountComplicatedData<TEntity>(Func<TEntity,bool> condition) {
    return database
        .Set<TEntity>()
        .SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM <Complicated Query Here>")
        .Count(condition);
}
```

Comment: I was afraid that was the case.  `Count` was just an example, the application uses the result in a variety of ways, and even then, it would still run the condition locally which is what I am trying to avoid.  Do you know if there is a way to translate the condition into a raw SQL query?  I can't find any open APIs in EF that allow me to do translation into real SQL.

Comment: @MrZander Unfortunately, I don't know of any such implementation. When I needed similar functionality for my project that uses [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper), I rolled my own implementation. I managed to pack a lot of functionality in under 300 lines of code by extending `ExpressionVisitor`. Unfortunately, my project is closed-source, so I cannot share any code from it.

Comment: Obviously, another approach is to parameterize your SQL query, but I assume that you have already thought about doing that, and dismissed it as too complex.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping I could "inject" my own table in place of the one it queries by default without too much of a performance hit.  That way I could leverage expressions to do the querying.   Thanks for the info!  I'll have to put in more work than I was hoping haha.